# Java: Testing if a String ends with a newline

Tags: java, string

I want to perform a `substring.equals("\n")`. In the code below, I take the last character and check if it is a newline.

```
String substring = nextResult.length() > 1 ? nextResult.substring(nextResult.length() - 1) : nextResult;            
return substring.equals("\n") ?  /* do stuff */ : /* do other stuff */;
```

I take only the last character because Java takes `\n` as one `char`. However, from what I see, `substring.equals("\n")` returns `true` for whitespaces (`" "`), and I think tabs (`\t`). Is that so?

How can I correctly check if the end of a string is a newline, or at least if the string is a newline?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with hardcoded Strings? We have no idea what nextResult is, so this is ipmossible to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that something is wrong with your nextResult variable, since this works fine for me:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println("\t".equals("\n")); //false
        System.out.println(" ".equals("\n")); //false
        System.out.println("\n".equals("\n")); //true
    }
}
```

Make sure that nextResult really contains what you think it does, and if so, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that uses hardcoded Strings to show us exactly what's going wrong.

Edit: I've modified the above example to use a substring, and it still works fine:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String... args){

        String endsWithNewline = "test\n";
        String substring = endsWithNewline.substring(4);

        System.out.println(substring.equals("\t")); //false
        System.out.println(substring.equals(" ")); //false
        System.out.println(substring.equals("\n")); //true
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. Equals works perfectly. I had a tree iteration which was concat-ing strings in abnormal way so there was always a `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 7):

You may use [`String#endsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-):

```
boolean endsWithNewline = nextResult.endsWith("\n");
```

Or [`String#charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-):

```
boolean endsWithNewLine = nextResult.charAt(nextResult.length() - 1) == '\n';
```

However, your current code works fine for me. Perhaps there is some kind of typo in your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't this work? Seems to be there at least since 1.5.0 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)

Comment: `.endsWith("\n")` is perfect. +1

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make much sense, and your input(s) cannot be what you seem to think they are -

```
// The first one will equal "\n" the second won't.
String[] arr = { "hi\n", "hi " };
for (String nextResult : arr) {
    String substring = nextResult.substring(nextResult.length() - 1);
    if (substring.equals("\n")) {
        System.out.println("Yes: " + nextResult);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No: " + nextResult);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
Yes: hi

No: hi
```

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of checking if something is a new line symbol I would use `Guava` `CharMatcher` class.

```
final String breakingWhitespace = "\n\r";
Assert.assertTrue(CharMatcher.BREAKING_WHITESPACE.matchesAllOf(whitespace));
```

There are also many other variations of matching:

- matches(char)
- matchesAllOf(CharSequence)
- matchesAnyOf(CharSequence)
- matchesNoneOf(CharSequence)

Look [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#CharMatcher) for documentation.

The main advantage of using this approach would be that it fits **really** many "new line" (or whitespace) characters (just [look at the code](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#line.67)).